# how to message from servlet and display in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm trying to do something that looks small but it's failing. I'm trying to send a response message back to a jsp when login fails but not being able. As of now I can only redirect back to the jsp but cannot display a message from the servlet on it. This is the servlet part of the redirection:

```
                if (count > 0) {
                res.sendRedirect("adminHome.jsp");
            } else {

                res.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }
```

I tried to print a message using PrintWriter and the redirect but failed because I couldn't get how to receive the message in the JSP. I also read that I shouldn't redirect but rather I should just forward from the servlet. How can I do this? Please help with the code patch to forward from servlet as well as that one to receive in JSP. Thanks

Comment: Never ever use `response.getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` in servlet whenever you use forward/redirect. You will risk `IllegalStateException`s.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you insist to use redirect instead of forward, then you have 2 options:

1. Pass the message as request parameter

   ```
   String message = "hello";
   res.sendRedirect("adminHome.jsp?message=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8"));
   ```

   so that you can display it in JSP as follows

   ```
   <p>Message: ${param.message}</p>
   ```

   It's only visible in the browser address bar as well and you aren't able to pass non-standard Java objects this way.
2. Store it in session

   ```
   String message = "hello";
   req.getSession().setAttribute("message", message);
   res.sendRedirect("adminHome.jsp");
   ```

   so that you can display (**and remove**) it in JSP as follows:

   ```
   <p>Message: ${message}</p>
   <c:remove var="message" scope="session" />
   ```

   Removing is important, otherwise it sticks there for the entire session.

---

However, if you're open to using forward instead of redirect, it's more elegant:

```
String message = "hello";
req.setAttribute("message", message);
req.getRequestDispatcher("/adminHome.jsp").forward(req, res);
```

and display it as follows in JSP

```
    <p>Message: ${message}</p>
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains a Hello World which also treats messaging
- [EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) - explains all about those `${}` things.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, I tried all your options and they give the display I need. Only problem is the message sticks to the page even when I restart the application. How can I remove it such that it only displays when username and password are incorrect? Now it displays the message even before username and password are entered

Comment: Which way have you used? If you've set it in the session **without** using `<c:remove>`, then it will indeed stick the entire session. Shutdown and restart the webbrowser. As to the right way of displaying validation messages, click the *Our Servlets wiki page* link at the "See also" section of my answer.

Comment: I restarted the browser and the message was gone. Thank you very much

Comment: yes adding and removing both are important,nice answer...

Answer (score 3):

Set your message as an attribute of the request object:

```
request.setAttribute("message", messageString);
```

Use a RequestDispatcher to dispatch the request and response objects to the jsp:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("urlString");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Access it in your JSP using Expression Language syntax:

```
${message}
```

Comment: Thanks @elekwent, Only problem now is it displays message on page even when nothing has been entered. How can I ensure that message only comes after something has been entered?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the message in the request and then forward to the jsp rather than redirect.

```
    request.setAttribute("msg", "The actual error message to be displayed");

    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/yourpage.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

Then on the jsp page you have access to the message via the request.

Comment: Thanks. It works though message seems to stick on page. How can it be removed