# Display success message in same jsp where form is submitted

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to display a success message in the same jsp page, if a user successfully creates an account.
**Jsp code:**

```
 <h3>Fill the below form to make an account:</h3><br>
        <div class="container">
          <form action="addAccount" method="post">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="cusName" placeholder="Your name.." required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="id">ID</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="number" id="id" name="cusId" placeholder="Enter an ID.." min="1" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="account">AccountID</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="number" id="account" name="accountID" placeholder="Enter an accountID.." min="1" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="deposit">Deposit</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="number" id="deposit" name="balance" placeholder="Enter deposit amount..">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </form>

**Java servlet:**       

AccountService as = new AccountService();
            String result = as.addAccount(newAccount);
            PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
            System.out.println(result);
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("done")){
                pw.write("Account Created Successfully");
            }
```

If I do this it is only printing the above message. I want to print the message above the form.

Comment: what `above message` ? i don't find any code in your jsp code where you are displaying message from your servlet ? please add more details related to your question.

Comment: I didn't write any jsp code, it only contains html tags right now. Message: "Account created successfully". The problem is I want to display a message, if account is created successfully on the same jsp page.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048156/10606400) answer, to achieve above .

Comment: Yes, its working now. Thanks